functions from imported module F are not recognized
Im making a tg bot with python using aiogram and i want to use F functions, but vscode does not recognize them. import works fine, F is imported, but F functions such as F.text.lower are not recognized. aiogram version is 3+ so  F should be included, also i tried importing from magic-filter, but functions are still not recognized.

By "not recognized", do you mean "don't work when I run the app", or do you just mean "my editor marks them with red squiggles"?

@TimRoberts I mean that vscode does not mark them with color and does not autocomplete them. I know that sometimes it does not mean that it will not work but in this case i dont think its like that, i think it means that theyre not recognized

Do you mean you haven't even tried the script?  Missing autocomplete is mildly annoying, but if the script works, it really is little more than an annoyance.  Is vscode using the same instance of Python as your command line?

@TimRoberts huh, I started recently so theres not much to run, but i assumed that if vscode does not recognize it it will not work? vscode is using the same instance yes

If the code compiles, then it's a problem with the IntelliSense, otherwise it's a coding problem.

@MinxinYu-MSFT okay thanks, ill finish my code and try to launch it, if it fails probably gonna create another question

No, the VSCode Python extension does its own syntax analysis.  It doesn't use the interpreter.
